# Phone contact list with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qml, contact-list

I just started learning Qt and would like to try creating phone contact list. Through I couldn't find from where to start. I would be glad for any suggestions.

Comment: In no particular order: design mockups, read the Qt documentation, figure out which widgets you want to use, actually design a window in Qt creator, research the datastructures you think you'll need, research storage techniques, think about the actual user interactions, figure out how to write said interactions.

Comment: And don't forget to experiment, make mistakes, and have fun. Nobody in their right mind would, say, store contacts as entries in a zip file, but it will teach you a lot.

Comment: https://qmlbook.github.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a phone contact list I suggest looking at [`QListWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html). It has functions to insert/remove items and you can get signals when items are altered or when a new item is clicked.